# Why is the Docker entrypoint script not starting?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

When i build the Dockerfile, the build is successful but the entrypoint script doesnot start. I also tried replacing `ENTRYPOINT ["scripts/run"]` with `ENTRYPOINT ["/tmp/files/run"]` but still didnot work. When I run the file directly from the command line, "Hello" is printed.
Dockerfile

```
FROM docker.repo1.uhc.com/confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:5.5.1
COPY scripts/run /tmp/files/run
RUN chmod +x /tmp/files/run
ENTRYPOINT ["scripts/run"]
```

scripts/run file

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Hello"
```

Console

```
Step 1/4 : FROM docker.repo1.uhc.com/confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:5.5.1
 ---> 8be0645d0a22
Step 2/4 : COPY scripts/run /tmp/files/run
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 5bf0b42480c0
Step 3/4 : RUN chmod +x /tmp/files/run
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 0d5c7b169a48
Step 4/4 : ENTRYPOINT ["scripts/run"]
 ---> Running in 0b2e45be4b75
Removing intermediate container 0b2e45be4b75
 ---> 887bfac238b0
Successfully built 887bfac238b0
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually in Docker ENTRYPOINT will execute while running the container using `Docker run <image-name>`. It will not execute while creating image.

Answer (score 1):

The correct entrypoint should be

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/tmp/files/run"]
```

And some extra notes:

- Append a file extension (in your case `.sh`)
- Don't use the `/tmp` folder. It's designed to keep only temporary files and it will be evicted on restarts.
- Entrypoint scripts are normally placed in `/`. Place it as `/entrypoint.sh`
- Don't use an URL in the `FROM`-clause. It's better to wrote `FROM confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:5.5.1`. If you using a mirror, then you can configure it in docker. Have a look [here](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/pulling-cached-images).

Comment: I have tried all these steps, none of them worked for me

Comment: Did you only build the image? You have to run `docker build . -t test` and then `docker run test`.

Comment: It is working with this command now! Does this mean that the entrypoint script just initialises the container, and a run command is required to actually start it?

Comment: The commands are only executed to build an image. The entrypoint marks the first command, when a images will be run.

Comment: Is there any way to automatically start the image, immediately after they are built? For deploying to production

Comment: No, building a image is like to compile a program. You can share a image with others. I recommend to not built images on production machines. Build an image (maybe local) and push it to your production server.

Comment: If I push a built image to kubernetes, will it start running automatically there? (I am sorry if this is a silly question, I am new to this)

Comment: No problem, I'm glad to help. No k8s will not build images. If you push a image somewhere, then k8s will pull and run it.